# Thermal Power Management in Fedora 20 vs Fedora 26?

Tags: fedora, power-management

I'm trying to track down the root cause of what appears to be a thermal related issue causing an Intel D2550 CPU powered, fanless WTM-N28 motherboard to go into what seems to be an emergency shut down mode.

With lm_sensors installed and monitoring the core temperature via the `sensors` command, as soon as the core temperature reaches ~70° C the motherboard shuts down.

We are running Fedora 20 with Linux kernel 3.16.

There were 5 motherboards that experienced this issue.  All 5 were sent back to the manufacturer for analysis, which confirmed there is no hardware issue.  They were able to determine however on two of the failing motherboards that loading either Fedora 26 or Windows 10 operating systems 'fixed' the power cycling issue.  Then, they reloaded Fedora 20 and the original failure was *still* seemingly resolved.

So the question becomes, focusing on the Fedora 20 vs. Fedora 26 scenario only, how can I effectively check for firmware, packages, or other updates that might have been installed during the Fedora 26 image that would not have been overwritten when going back to Fedora 20?

I've been filtering through loads of Fedora documentation on FedoraProject, Archlinux, Bugzilla, etc..  and I'm not sure I've found anything relevant enough to help me diagnose.

Comment: Do you have there the same firmware (BIOS/UEFI) as before. Is it possible manufacturer updated it and it solved your issue? If there was complete reinstall, drivers from F26 couldn't survive it.

Comment: Yes, they used the same BIOS setup.  American Megatrends WTM-N28 version 1.4 (PCB3.0)  Before they loaded Fedora 26 they did try updating to a newer BIOS version and confirmed the issue was still present.  They reverted back to the originally installed version before trying the F26 upgrade.  From what I gathered from them it was not a complete reinstall.